# Can I force Perl Devel::Cover to generate a coverage report if I killed the build testcover process before it was finished?

Tags: perl, reporting, code-coverage, kill

If I am able to start up Devel::Cover successfully and it starts to collect data in the cover_db directory, can I then kill the process and then after the fact get Devel::Cover or some other utility to process those binary Devel::Cover run files and structure files into the HTML coverage report?

To ask the question another way ... Can I use Devel::Cover to get a coverage report for a process that I am unable to stop, other than by killing the process?

This question is related to: [How do I get code coverage of Perl CGI script when executed by Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901293/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I usually handle this (say, for running tests on servers) is:

- Generate a `__DIE__` handler for the Perl process. This ensures that the process completes normally and Devel::Cover finishes the DB population
- Send SIGINT to the process to trigger the new DIE handler.
- run [`cover`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-Cover/cover) program on the cover_db directory after the process is dead.

Comment: Perfect!  I'm just now realizing that most of these awesome Perl modules also are available from the command line.  Genius!